# How to pass data from cron to Controller laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cron

How how can i transfer data from cron(sheduler) to Controller which make json in laravel
this is my route:

```
Route::get("/data",'DataController@Data');
```

and this is my function Data in controller:

```
    public function Data(){
    return response()->json(['data'-> User::all()],200);
}
```

And how can i make cron which will make query to mysql for User, save in variable and pass to my controller?

Update:
I try to use Cache:
in my command(which will be run by crontab)

```
    public function handle()
{
    $data = User::All();
    Log::info('Data: ' . $data);
    Cache::put('data',$data);
    Log::info('Done!');
    Log::info('Data: ' . Cache::get('data'));
}
```

problem is fact that First info() printf me good data but when i try to get from cache i got nothink, i try to storage data to File
CACHE_DRIVER=file (from .env)
i run page on windows, and storage folder has permissions to create files

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do makes no sense at all. The scheduler is being run through a CLI interface, which has nothing to do with the Controllers.

I would highly recommend you to not mix the Scheduler and Controllers, but instead create Helper-classes for methods, that you might have to reuse.

If you want to run the Controller anyway, you can run it with something like:

```
(new App\Http\Controllers\DataController())->Data()
```

*Disclaimer: I'm not completely sure on how the response and request classes behaves, when you call a Controller outside of the normal Request-lifecycle.*

Comment: problem is fact i use this data in Ajax(java-scripts) and ajax run around (5times per second) and when i make query to mysql 5 time per second per one viewer my database will die... and i want to make somethink like cache and function Data() will return data from cache and cron will update data in cache